# What's the point of donating money?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

I found this donation machine in a shop room in The Binding of Isaac: Rebirth. I have put 20 coins in it with no results. I tried to explode it, but it just spat some of my money back out at me! What does it do?

[image: donation machine]

Comment: If you've put 20 coins in it you should've had two things unlock, shop leveup up and blue map appearing in the basement (at 20 and 10 coins respectively)

Answer (score 2):

Donating money unlocks more (and probably better) shop items.

For example - at 10 donated coins, I unlocked a blue map.

Comment: There are lots of items to get out of donations, once you get to 50, isn't every 50 for a while?